# Как добавлять br либо перенос строки в текстовой области настройки магазина?

Tags: opencart

в настройках магазина есть возможность оставлять комментарий. Как туда добавить br, иначе текст в одну большую кашу складывается

Comment: input > textbox

Comment: @Kirill не совсем понимаю что вы имейте ввиду

Comment: Случайно увидел вопрос(очередь проверок), не шарю в `html`, но я думаю, что он советует использовать тег `textbox` вместо тега `input`.

Comment: если элемент формы, где вы пишите - input (тип), его надо переписать в textarea

Comment: @Kirill, суть в том что он и так textarea, но переноса в textarea нету)